# How to pass a parameter with space to an external program in a shell script?

Tags: shell, shellexecute, shell-exec

a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
description=`"test message"` # input parameter for contain a space

binary=<external_prog> # simply display what passes to flag --description

cmd="$binary --description=$description"

$cmd # run the external program
```

Question: message will miss, how to resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
description="test message"
binary=program

cmd="$binary --description=\"$description\""

eval $cmd
```

or just run

```
$binary --description="$description"
```

Answer (score 0):

The back-ticks in this are not wanted, unless you really have a program called 'test message' (with space in the name) that generates your desired output:

```
description=`"test message"` # input parameter for contain a space
```

The simplest way to achieve your requirement is to use double quotes around the (part of the) argument that needs to contain spaces:

```
description="test message"
binary=external_prog
$binary --description="$description"
```

You could equivalently write the last line as:

```
$binary "--description=$description"
```

This ensures that all the material in description is treated as a single argument, blanks and all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash or ksh or some shell with arrays, they are the safest way to contruct a command. In bash:

```
description="test message"
binary=some_prog
cmd=( "$binary" "--description=$description" )
"${cmd[@]}"
```

You can test it with something like this: say this is named "arg_echoer.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0"
i=0
for arg in "$@"; do
    let i="$i+1"
    echo "$i: $arg"
done
```

Then, if `binary=./arg_echoer.sh`, you get this output with `"${cmd[@]}"`

```
./arg_echoer.sh
1: --description=test message
```

Answer (score 0):

The safe way is to [use an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050):

```
args=("--description=test message" "--foo=some other message")
args+=("--bar=even more")
cmd "${args[@]}"
```